# ActionMailer.net/ActionMailerNext - how to confirm if an eMail has even been sent?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, actionmailer, actionmailer.net

Working with `ActionMailerNext`, which is a fork of the now-dead **ActionMailer.net**, and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to determine if the eMail has been sent, or if an error occurred that prevented the eMail from being sent.

Neither site provides any idea on how to do this. Two hours of Googling has been similarly productive (NOT!).

Typically, with something like a database update, I can do a

```
if((await _db.SaveChangesAsync()) > 0){ ... }
```

and be able to fork the code between yes-it-updated and no-it-failed portions. I need to be able to do this with ActionMailerNext, and I haven’t a clue how.

The actual `.Deliver()` returns a

```
System.Collections.Generic.IList<ActionMailerNext.Interfaces.IMailResponse>
```

But I have no clue how to unpack it because I have no idea what is inside it. Any attempt to google `IMailResponse` does not bring me back anything of use.

---

EDIT:

For those who would like to know, the returned collection contains two variables: a string `Email` and an Enum called DeliveryStatus that provides one of four responses for each eMail sent: DELIVERED, INVALID, QUEUED and REJECTED. By doing the following, even if only one eMail was sent (because my needs are simple):

```
if(e.All(x => x.DeliveryStatus == DeliveryStatus.DELIVERED)) {
  // Do if ALL eMails were sent
} else {
  // Fallback if ANY eMail was not sent
}
```

I was able to ensure that a fallback existed if one or more eMails failed to get sent.

Keep in mind, though: this only is for eMails getting delivered to the outgoing SMTP server; the system has no clue what happens beyond that.

Thanks to @ADyson below for the poke needed for my sleep-deprived brain to function correctly.

Comment: does intellisense not help you? Or you should be able to right-click on IMailResponse in Visual Studio and click Go To Definition, which should at least give you a list of properties.

Comment: It was very late, I was bone tired, and I was chasing my tail. Not a good combination. I was assigning the `.Deliver()` to a variable, but only doing a generic `var` up. When I replaced `var` with `List<IMailResponse>` I was able to dig into and unpack the item to find what I needed. Thanks for the poke in the right direction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For those who would like to know, the returned collection contains two variables: a string `Email` and an Enum called DeliveryStatus that provides one of four responses for each eMail sent: DELIVERED, INVALID, QUEUED and REJECTED. By doing the following, even if only one eMail was sent (because my needs are simple):

```
if(e.All(x => x.DeliveryStatus == DeliveryStatus.DELIVERED)) {
  // Do if ALL eMails were sent
} else {
  // Fallback if ANY eMail was not sent
}
```

I was able to ensure that a fallback existed if one or more eMails failed to get sent.

Keep in mind, though: this only is for eMails getting delivered to the outgoing SMTP server; the system has no clue what happens beyond that.

Thanks to @ADyson for the poke needed for my sleep-deprived brain to function correctly.